# Changing Ableton UI's colors

Tags: ableton-live

I'm looking for a program that will let me change colors of Live's theme, mostly clip colors, I require the theme to be compatible with Live 8 & 9, here is theme: http://www.mediafire.com/file/o6w8vjndoght40t/04Disco.ask/file, if you are going to recommend anything, see if it doesn't show all colors as black like some editors do, I may also change theme in hex if nothing else helps, knowing what to change, any clues?

Comment: can you add screenshot instead of the theme file? not everyone uses the same version as yours. thank you

Comment: Live 10 has changed themes Live supports, it doesn't make sense to help if you're on it, you would need to know about editor that works also for previous versions, if somebody is using Live 8 or Live 9 it opens easily in both and if you actually read question, theme is more useful, it lets you check out editor on it instead of visually matching. You possibly got used to dictate in ur studio too much :).